# Can't setup nutch-2.3 and solr-4.1.0 in Ubuntu -14.04

Tags: solr

I am new to `nutch` and `solr`. `Nutch-1.12` and `solr-5.2.1` integrate successfully but nut `nutch-2.3` and `solr-4.1.0` are not integrating.

```
WARNINGS [ivy:resolve] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve] :: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES :: [ivy:resolve] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve] :: org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6: configuration not found in org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.gora#gora-core;0.6.1 compile [ivy:resolve] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve] [ivy:resolve] [ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS BUILD FAILED D:\apachenutch\build.xml:468: impossible to resolve dependency
```

Please help me to figure out the installation problem.

Comment: Add some more info where you facing problem or any error message.

Comment: WARNINGS [ivy:resolve]
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve]
:: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES :: [ivy:resolve]
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve]
:: org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6: configuration not found in org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.gora#gora-core;0.6.1 compile [ivy:resolve]
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve] [ivy:resolve] [ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
BUILD FAILED D:\apachenutch\build.xml:468: impossible to resolve dependency

Comment: From next time add these error messages in question not in the comment box. Try this `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: We dont need hbase for nutch-2.3 and solr-4.1.0 integration ?